# Allow us to edit the image in tour page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams

The stackoverflow image on the tour page on the channels is not editable. It would be nice to be able to edit it.

[image]

Comment: Or if it would just use the logo it's already using for the Channel.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no longer a tour page specific to each team. Ultimately we want to integrate the content of the tour page into a contextual on-boarding experience. That way it is more bite-sized and relevant to what you're doing. That work will happen after Team's launch.